# Unable to create a web policy agent profile in Access Management 5.1

Tags: tomcat, openam, forgerock

I testing new product from ForgeRock - AM 5.1 but have issues right after deployment of a war file.

I created post on [forge-rock forum](https://forum.forgerock.com/topic/unable-to-create-a-web-policy-agent-profile-in-access-management-5-1/#post-18461) (where it has log entries and java versions that I've used) and maybe someone here had similar problem and solved it?

Any advice is really appreciated.

Thank you,
Ernest

Answer (score 0):

Installing tomcat8 solved the problem.